# Query MongoDb from C# - using Linq .Any() with predicate

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection I am trying to query using the c# driver. the document structure is:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 3121 , 
    "Active" : true , 
    "CategoryId" : 1 , 
    "Crci" : "IH" , 
    "CultureId" :  null  , 
    "DateUpdated" : { 
            "$date" : 1381916923120
    } , 
    "Description" : "National Careers Service: Actuary" , 
    "Keywords" : "" , 
    "MaxLevel" :  null  , 
    "MinLevel" :  null  , 
    "PhoneNumber" : "                    " , 
    "Priority" : 1 , 
    "Title" : "National Careers Service: Actuary" , 
    "WebUrl" : "https://nationalcareersservice.direct.gov.uk/advice/planning/jobprofiles/Pages/actuary.aspx" , 
    "CareerCultureExternalResources" : [ 
            { 
                    "CareerId" : 5 , 
                    "CultureId" : 1 , 
                    "DisplayOrder" : 1 , 
                    "ExternalResourceId" : 3121 , 
                    "Vgs" :  null 
            }
    ] , 
    "SubjectExternalResources" : [ ] , 
    "LifestyleCategories" :  null
}
```

the query I am trying to run is:

```
collection.AsQueryble().Where(
                er =>
                er.CareerCultureExternalResources.Any(
                    ccer => ccer.CareerId == request.CareerId && ccer.CultureId == request.CultureId));
```

passing the values `careerId = 637` and `cultureId = 1`, I get the error: `"Unsupported where clause: ((Int32)ccer.CareerId == 637)"`

However on the MongoDb tutorials page it says this kind of query is covered:
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/

I am using version 1.8.3 of the driver

Comment: Are the data types matching?  Is `CareerId` on `request` an Int32?

Comment: Use Query class to build your queries like this: Query.EQ("CareerId", request.CareerId).

Comment: @WiredPrairie That's one of the interesting things - the `CareerId` is a short and so is the data type for the 'CareerCultureExternalResource`. So the data types match but the error doesn't make sense. I'm not sure why it is trying to cast it to an `int`

Comment: @bradciven I'd rather keep to using linq rather than the query builder except for exceptional circumstances. One of the reasons we chose mongo was its excellent Linq support

Comment: Can you try with an `int`? From a quick read of a few spots around, it sounds like not all data types are supported equally in the `where`.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Thank you, that sorted it, you're offically a mongo genius. If you add that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, using `where` and a conditional clause like you've done, when using Linq, is limited to a subset of .NET data types. Instead of using a `short`, use a `Int32`/(`int`) instead.